# Java debug probe

Tags: java, debugging

I want to find a way to do a debug probe in Java. I'm used to working in Wingware Python IDE and it lets me set a breakpoint and once the execution reaches it, I have a Python shell, where I can execute arbitrary Python code in the context of a place, where the execution is paused. So I want to do the same in Java, i.e. set a breakpoint and get to know what would certain code do if I'd place it directly after that bp.

Edit:
I'm using Eclipse. Where should I type? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any decent IDE will do this (e.g. Eclipse, Intellij or Netbeans). They will let you evaluate Java arbitrary expressions, so you can hit a breakpoint and then execute code based on the variables available to you.

An alternative is to use [jdb](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdb.html) - the command line debugger that comes with the JDK. That permits evaluation of simple Java expressions.

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse, after you stop at a breakpoint, you can use the Display view (Window → Show View → Other... → Display) to write down an expression, and evaluate it by selecting (i.e. highlight the text with the mouse) and pressing `Ctrl+Shift+I`. It's very handy!